# Why is it impossible to implement a generic interface multiple times with different type parameters?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface:

```
public static interface Consumer<T> {
    void consume(T t);
}
```

And I want to be able to have:

```
public static class Foo implements Consumer<String>, Consumer<Integer> {
    public void consume(String t) {..}
    public void consume(Integer i) {..}
}
```

It doesn't work - the compiler doesn't let you implement the same interface twice.

The question is: **Why?**

People have asked similar questions here, but the answer was always "type erasure", i.e. you cannot do it because the types are erased at runtime.

And they aren't - some types are retained at runtime. And they are retained in this particular case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) Foo.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
    System.out.println(type.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
}
```

This prints `class java.lang.String` (if I only keep `Consumer<String>` in order to compile)

So, erasure, in its simplest explanation, is not the reason, or at least it needs elaboration - the type is there, and also, you don't care about the type resolution, because you already have two methods with distinct signature. Or at least it seems so.

Comment: (I have an answer that I'm almost sure about, but I'd like to know is there a 'canonical' one :) )

Comment: What would you count as a "canonical" answer? A quote from the JLS gospel precluding that possibility? I wouldn't find that satisfying at all. The answer you have in mind is probably better than that.

Comment: About it written in many books.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer is still "type erasure", but it's not that simple. The keywords are: **raw types**

Imagine the following:

```
Consumer c = new Foo();
c.consume(1);
```

What would that do? It appears that `consume(String s)` is not actually `consume(String s)` - it is still `consume(Object o)`, even though it is defined to take `String`.

So, the above code is ambiguous - the runtime can't know which of the two `consume(..)` methods to invoke.

A funny follow-up example is to remove `Consumer<Integer>`, but keep the `consume(Integer i)` method. Then invoking the `c.consume(1)` on a raw `Consumer`. throws `ClassCastException` - unable to cast from Integer to String. The curious thing about this exception is that it happens on *line 1*.

The reason is the use of [bridge methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html#bridgeMethods). The compiler generates the bridge method:

```
public void consume(Object o) {
    consume((String) o);
}
```

The generated bytecode is:

```
public void consume(java.lang.String);

public void consume(java.lang.Integer);

public void consume(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: aload_1
     2: checkcast     #39                 // class java/lang/String
     5: invokevirtual #41                 // Method consume:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

So even if the methods you have defined keep their signatures, each of them has a corresponding bridge method that is actually invoked when working with the class (regardless whether it's raw or parameterized).

Comment: Another level of answer would be that, even if raw types were precluded, supporting this would completely break the existing method invocation machinery. The `Consumer` interface has `consume(Object)` and the implementing class must have the same. So the primary goal of keeping backward compatibility would be defeated.

Answer (score 3):

@Bozho: Thanks for your profound question and your own answer. Even I was at this doubt at some stage.

Plus to add more to your answer, I'd disagree with you on this point in your question:

**"some types are retained at runtime"**.

Answer is **NO** because of type erasure (which you already pointed it out). Nothing is retained.

Now to answer this key doubt, "**how does it then knows the exact type after erasure ?**", check out the very definition of [ParameterizedType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html).

> When a parameterized type p is created, the generic type declaration that p instantiates is resolved

May be this resolution of exact [TypeVariable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) is obtained through what you specified as [bridge methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html#bridgeMethods)

Comment: From the bytecode: `public class ClassTest$Foo extends ClassTest$ConsumerClass<java.lang.String>` it is retained :)

Comment: Ahh... then that means, type erasure is not exactly what actually we used to think, just a sort of cover up to support backward compatibility to Java without Generics.